# Pump/PSI issues

Tags: tire, innertube, tire-pressure

Good afternoon

I have recently bought/installed new inner tubes and tyres (26" x 1.95") for my bike as attached (https://www.vandorm.co.uk/collections/26/products/vandorm-26-schrader-valve-inner-tube and https://www.vandorm.co.uk/collections/26-tyres/products/vandorm-city-slick-mountain-bike-tyre-26-x-2-30). I have tried getting the tyres to the correct psi (tyre says 50 but would set to 45 normally) but my track pump won’t read any more than 25 psi so bought a single barrel foot pump and it won’t register any more than 30 psi. The tyres feel like they have enough air in them and feel solid. Both of the pumps can pump up other items ok so im presuming its either the tubes, tyres or both? Both appears to be seated fine on the rims/wheels with no bulges etc. I am contemplating taking them to a garage and using the machine that I would use to pump up my car tyres, would that be too much or ok? Any other suggestions I can try?

​
Thanks

​
Gary

Comment: Can your pumps achieve a pressure of 50 on other tires?  There is generally a max pressure that a given pump can achieve, based on its geometry.  Most floor pumps should be able to achieve 80-100, but there are exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are not just underestimating the pressure the tyres need? You can of course use an air compressor if you have one in your garage. I do that myself both with an MTB bike and with a road bike. Just be sure to have the correct pressure there because it could be easy to over-inflate the tyre. Just pump your compressor to the pressure you need and add some air later if needing more.

Comment: Vladimir F - I'm fairly sure the pumps are ok as they can pump other tyres etc to the correct psi but not the new ones. Don't know if it maybe has something to do with the 2.5mm anti puncture material in the tyre? Tried everything I can think of.

Comment: @Gary I did not mean to suggest the pumps are wrong. Rather that you may need to continue pumping.

Comment: Vladimir F - ah ok, yeah I have tried continually but it gets to a point that the pumps stop allowing me to put any more in.

Answer (score 1):

I once accidentally exploded an inner tube in a 26" x 1-1/4" tire using the compressor at an automobile repair shop.  It exploded close to my head, because I was holding the hose to the tire valve stem.  Wow, what a loud bang it made!  If you decide to use the compressor at your mechanic's garage, be very careful.

I've never heard of a pump that wouldn't allow me to keep pumping more air by putting more of my weight on the handle.  Are you sure you're pressing hard enough?

Perhaps the problem is your pressure gauge?